# Mongodb database with multiple unique indexes in sharded config

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a "users" collection in a database in mongodb. I will be using sharding.

Other than the standard _id, there are 3 other fields that need to be indexed and unique: username, email, and account number. All 3 of these fields will not necessarily exist for every user document, in some cases none will exist.

I'd like the fields to be indexed because users will be looked up frequently by one of these fields. I'd like the fields to be unique because this is a requirement and I'd rather not handle this logic client-side.

I understand that mongodb does have limitations, just like any other database, but I'm hoping there's a solution because this is a fairly common setup for web applications.

Is there an elegant solution for this scenario?

Not sure if it matters for this question (because the question pertains to database structure), but I am using the official mongodb C# driver.

Answer (score 3):

Mongodb official documentation says, that sharded collection must have only one unique index, and requires the unique field(s) to exist. But it also [says](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Limits) that *you also have the option to have other unique indices if and only if the shard key is a prefix of their attributes.* So you can try this, but aware, that unique key must always exist.

I don't understand your business logic where no information about the user would exist. In this case you can shard by `_id` and perform uniqueness checks manually.

Comment: In order for sharding to be efficient the mongos process need to be able to pick a shard based only on the document, then send the write only to that shard. The requirement that a document have a unique key not in the shard index means all shards must be checked. This results in inserts that perform as slow as the slowest shard.  Do you really have enough users that you need to shard this table?